# Select not changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a selection hooked up to my model that has a key and value. I have a ngModelChange hooked up to a function to check what the selection value is. The selection shows the key to the user and the model change shows the value to the controller. However, when i try to get the Key from selection model is just shows the value that i instantiated it to.  How do i get the key from my selection?

Page

```
<select name="sel1" class="form-control" [ngModel]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" >
    <option [value]="item.value" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.key}}</option>
<select>
```

Component

```
private items:Array<any> = [
    { key:"Price", value:"itemPrice" },
    { key:"Year Made", value:"itemYear" },
    { key:"Model", value:"itemModel" },
    { key:"Customer Rating", value:"itemRating" },
    { key:"Newest Arrivals", value:"itemNewAriv" },
]; 
private selectedItem = this.items[0]; 
onChange(value) {
    console.log("Test"); 
    console.log(value); 
    console.log(this.selectedItem.key);  // Does not change 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `item` is an object (not a string) then `[ngValue]` should be used instead of `[value]`:

```
 <option [ngValue]="item"
```

Comment: Okay, but selectedItem value doesn’t change.

Comment: I forgot to remove `.value` in the binding. The `<select>` is missing a `/` in the closing tag. Actually it should work with your code as well because `key` is actually a string. I missed that. `private selectedItem = this.items[0]; ` is invalid though. It should be `private selectedItem = this.items[0].key;` in your code.